# How to read two values from array and determine which one is bigger?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to programming and I was given a challenge that I'm stuck.

We have an array (Integer[][] matches) with several arrays with scores for each match (Integer[] match_result). If match_result[0] is bigger than match_result[1], its counted as a win. If match [0] is smaller than match[1], its counted as a loss. If they're equal, it's a tie. I need to determine the percentage of wins, losses and ties from the total amount of matches. Here is what I was given originally:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Integer[][] matches = {{2,2},{3,2},{4,1},{1,3},{3,5},{1,1},{1,0},{0,0},{1,2},{0,2},{0,3},{3,3},{1,0}};
    System.out.println(results(matches));

}

public static String results(Integer[][] matches){
    Integer percentWin = 0;
    Integer percentLoss = 0;
    Integer percentTie = 0;
    Integer amountOfMatches = 13;

    for (int i = 0; i<amountOfMatches; i++){
        Integer nrMatch = i;
        Integer[] match_result;

    }

    return "Wins: " + percentWin + " Losses: " + percentLoss + " Ties: " + percentTie;
}
```

}

And here is what I wrote. I left some comments where I'm having issues:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Integer[][] matches = {{2,2},{3,2},{4,1},{1,3},{3,5},{1,1},{1,0},{0,0},{1,2},{0,2},{0,3},{3,3},{1,0}};
    System.out.println(results(matches));

}

public static String results(Integer[][] matches){
    Integer percentWin = 0;
    Integer percentLoss = 0;
    Integer percentTie = 0;
    Integer amountOfMatches = 13;


Integer win=0; //added by me
Integer lost=0; //added by me
Integer tie=0; //added by me

    for (int i = 0; i<amountOfMatches; i++){
        Integer nrMatch = i;
        Integer[] match_result;


        //added by from here down

        match_result = matches[i];//edited thanks to user:immibis


            if (match_result[0]>match_result[1]) 
            win++;
            else if (match_result[0]<match_result[1])
            lost++;
            else
            tie++;


        percentWin= (win/amountOfMatches)*100;
        percentLoss= (lost/amountOfMatches)*100;
        percentTie= (tie/amountOfMatches)*100;

    }


//it's not returning the percentages, any idea why???
    return "Wins: " + percentWin + " Losses: " + percentLoss + " Ties: " + percentTie;
}
```

}

Comment: `match_result = matches[i];`?

Comment: thank you immibis! Just updated the code. Any idea why the percentWin, percentLoss and percentTie are coming back as 0?

Comment: Integer math. `int percentWin = (int) (100 * ((double) win / amountOfMatches));`

Comment: @Joey Say there are 100 games and 70 of them are losses. 70 / 100 == 0. 0 * 100 == 0.

Comment: thanks a lot Elliot and immibis. I'm going to check all of this around. Code is working great now.